# Things needed to perform an activity - requisite or requirement? Or something else?

Tags: meaning

I'm designing an application to help tour operators with their operational tasks. I have something that I currently call "requisites", which is what is necessary to perform a certain tour. Common requisites for a tour will be a guide and a vehicle. Sometimes there may be other things, such as a driver, or horses, a boat etc.

A friend of mine, who is a native English speaker (as opposed to me) tells me this word, "requisite", isn't a word that's used much, and that a better, more understandable word would be "requirement".

I'm looking for the word that's not only more fitting, but also understandable. Which word would be best used between the two? Or maybe even a totally different word? Thank you!

Comment: Required and Requisite are synonyms. Your friend is right, though, 'requisite' is used less often (except, perhaps, 'prerequisite' meaning a thing that must be completed before moving forward to the next thing). I suspect native English speakers will understand 'required' best. See: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8776/under-what-circumstances-should-i-use-requisite-and-required

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "requisite".  Even if it's less popular, you wouldn't want to employ someone who doesn't know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider these two words in their noun forms:

> The university has an **entry requirement**.

**Requirement**, as defined by Collins's Dictionary, is something *imposed or demanded* as an obligation. Therefore, requirement, by definition, has a degree of arbitrariness. Here, the university decides to arbitrarily impose this on students.

> No matter how hard they try, they simply do not possess the **requisite skills** to do the job.

**Requisite** is something *indispensable or necessary for some purpose*. It implies that something is essential or vital. In this case, the persons trying cannot be hired because they lack the skills, which are absolutely necessary for the job.

Now I hope that this has clarified the meaning for you. But whether *requisite* or *requirement* is correct depends absolutely on the context of your sentence. Perhaps you could give us a precise one?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's actually not used in a sentence. It's a kind of item in this tour operator software I'm developing. It is the items listed as things that are needed to perform a tour. The tour operator will then make sure all of these listed items have been organized/booked in, to make sure it will be possible to execute the tour without having forgotten anything.